# Make: Include file causes "Permission denied" while trying to compile kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, make, gcc

I am trying to compile linux-5.18.1.
I downloaded the tar ball, unpacked it and ran `make defconfig`. If I then run `make`, I run into this problem after a while:

```
drivers/gpu/drm/i915/gt/intel_rps.c:16:10: fatal error: ./include/../../../platform/x8
6/intel_ips.h: Permission denied
   16 | #include "../../../platform/x86/intel_ips.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I get this error even if I run `chmod -R 777 .`  on the entire directory. I have tried to re-download several times.

The permissions of the header shouldn't be a problem:

```
ls -la drivers/platform/x86/intel_ips.h
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user-group 123 May 30 09:29 drivers/platform/x86/intel_ips.h
```

The same happens with linux-5.15.44. I am using GCC 9.3.0.
I don't have root access to this machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to successfully compile the kernel using `make -j 48`. The problem was that the working directory was not physically on the computing node that was performing the actual compilation, so going over the network somehow caused this issue.

Copying the linux-5.18.1 directory directly to the node and performing the compilation there locally worked fine. Unfortunately I don't know any more details about the network topology or the computing nodes themselves, so I can't tell what the exact cause was.

Thanks for the comments.